# OBS Studio is still black screen on ubuntu 18.04 LTS Xorg with nvidia

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 18.04, wayland, obs-studio

when I use Intel CPU as my gpu OBS works properly but when I switch to Nvidia (390 driver), then it shows just black screen. 
I changed this file :

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and removed `WaylandEnable=false` from comment.

then restarted, but nothing is happened and still OBS studio shows black screen with my Nvidia driver.
please help ! thanks.

Comment: What are the outputs of `echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP` and `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` in Terminal?

Comment: first command : ubuntu and the other one : x11

Comment: Hello, any work around ?

Comment: I did many things for solving that but nothing happened, and no one answered yet

Comment: and sorry gtzinos after many hacks around nvidia and graphical things in linux finally I decided to unistall my linux and install a windows 10 and run any linux just in a virtualbox and now I really enjoy my life.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. I would prefer to keep Linux on my devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Ubuntu 18.04, after Nvidia driver installation OBS window capture stopped work at all. Just giving black screen.
For me helped Mesa utils installation:

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

Also check your opengl version.

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

The app mesa-utils was missing in my case. After installation OBS window capture function works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This challenge can potentially be resolve using either **[obs-xdg-portal](https://gitlab.gnome.org/feaneron/obs-xdg-portal)** or **[obs-gnome-screencast](https://github.com/fzwoch/obs-gnome-screencast)** free and open source plugins.

Attribution & details at https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/running-obs-in-wayland.32165/post-492672

Comment: Link seems to be dead, but even if you can fix that, would be good if you could add the details here